# sending Multiple emails from database query

Tags: php, mysql, email

Hello I want to send emails to a list of contacts from my database. Code does not select database. I would like to know what I could do to fix this. this code seems to work till to get to the `mysql_query` command. This only error it returns it the database is not selected and it fails. I echoed the code line for line and it does not pass the `$rs = mysql_query($query_Events, $gpd) or die(mysql_error());` command.
Please help me understand how I cant correctly fix this.

```
 <?php 


$hostname_gpd = "127.0.0.1";
$database_gpd = "localmail";
$username_gpd = "";
$password_gpd = "";
$gpd = mysqli_connect($hostname_gpd, $username_gpd, $password_gpd) or  trigger_error(mysqli_error(),E_USER_ERROR)
; 

$subject=$_POST['Subject'];
$note=$_POST['Message'];

$sender="xxxx@yahoo.com"; // Your Email here.

echo "Email has been sent to:";

// Connect database

mysqli_select_db($gpd,$database_gpd);

$query_Events = "SELECT `Email` FROM email_list ORDER BY `id` ASC";

$rs = mysqli_query($gpd,$query_Events) or die(mysqli_error($gpd));

if(!$rs)
{

echo mysqli_error();
}
else{       // Do while loop to send email.
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs)){
$to=$row['Email'];
$mail_from="From:$Email n";
$mail_from .="Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8 n";

mail($to,$subject,$note,$mail_from);

// Show sent emails.
echo "$row[Email]<br>";
}}

?>
```

Comment: Please don't use the `mysql_` functions. They are deprecated. Instead, use `mysqli_` or `PDO`.

Comment: upgraded commands to sqli . . debuged my errors and now i only get a No database selected

Comment: Post your updated code, then.

Comment: Don't post code in comments. @user3259517 update your question instead.

Comment: These two lines are invalid `$mail_from="From:$Email n";` and `$mail_from .="Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8 n";` @user3259517 it's not just a `n` it's `\n` and needs an `\r` also, so that it is `\r\n`

Comment: And you still need the fourth parameter in `$gpd = mysqli_connect($hostname_gpd, $username_gpd, $password_gpd)` do `$gpd = mysqli_connect($hostname_gpd, $username_gpd, $password_gpd,$database_gpd)` @user3259517 Read >>> http://www.php.net/mysqli_select_db

Comment: hey i made your changes and got a few errors then fix them now it looks like the code works. i would like to know do i have to add more code to get a email to pop up in my email now or should it be sending real emails

Comment: See my answer below, it's been tested and working perfectly. Just make sure that everything matches to a `"T"`. @user3259517 - This should basically "Run out of the Box" ;-)

Comment: It should be sending real email. You won't know really if it was received or not. @user3259517 Try it with a test table using your Email or more, if you do have more than one Email account.

Comment: hey thanks and it is set up to send the emails to my two email accounts , if i do not get them should i check out mail() and im running local xampp

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help. I don't know how xampp works for mailer stuff. If it works in its present state, great. But you will need to use `mail()` or PHPmailer. I think some have used that for it before. @user3259517 - I run all my code off a hosted service, so everything is already setup.

Comment: well on the test server i hear of people changing sendmail.ini and php.ini would i need to set any of those up . also i have a remoter godaddy server i can upload it to do you think it will run out of the box on the remote server

Comment: Theoretically, it should run out of the box on GoDaddy, but many have had issues before where GoDaddy refused to send mail if a sender and/or recipient was Yahoo, Gmail etc. Go figure eh? You pay for a service and you can't get the mail out.

Comment: its running on godaddy. thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a few issues with your code.

Your [`mail() headers`](http://php.net/mail) were invalid, missing `\r\n` where you only had `n` and those have been reformatted.

Conclusive test Emails did not go to SPAM in Yahoo and Gmail and landed in Inbox.

I also added the database parameter; that needed to be in there, even though you declared it using [`mysqli_select_db()`](http://www.php.net/mysqli_select_db)

The `From:` should have been using the `$sender` variable and not `$Email` because everyone who would receive an Email, would see it as coming from "them", and I doubt that's what you want to do.

**(Tested and working for me)** and assuming that [`mail()`](http://php.net/mail) is available, properly setup and running on your server.

```
<?php
$hostname_gpd = "127.0.0.1";
$database_gpd = "localmail";
$username_gpd = "";
$password_gpd = "";
$gpd = mysqli_connect($hostname_gpd, $username_gpd, $password_gpd, $database_gpd) 
or  trigger_error(mysqli_error(),E_USER_ERROR);

$subject=$_POST['Subject'];
$note=$_POST['Message'];

/* my testing variables
$subject= "The subject";
$note= "My little note";
*/

$sender="xxxx@yahoo.com"; // Your Email here.
echo "Email has been sent to: ";

$query_Events = "SELECT `Email` FROM email_list ORDER BY `id` ASC";
$rs = mysqli_query($gpd,$query_Events) or die(mysqli_error($gpd));

if(!$rs)
{
echo mysqli_error();
}
else{ // Do while loop to send email.
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs)){
    $to=$row['email'];

$mail_from = "From: $sender" . "\r\n" . "Reply-To: $sender" . "\r\n";
$mail_from .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8 \r\n";

mail($to,$subject,$note,$mail_from);

// Show sent emails.
// echo "$row[email]<br>";
echo "$row[email]" . "<br>";
    }
}
?>
```

---

Also make sure that your form elements are named and matches your PHP handler variables.

For example:

```
<form action="handler.php" method="post">
Enter subject: <input type="text" name="Subject">
<br>
Enter message:
<br>
<textarea rows="5" name="Message" cols="50"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Lettercase is important for `POST` variables, where you presently are using mixed-case letters.

`Subjet` is not the same as `subject`, as is `Message` is not the same as `message`